# How to use composition API to create a new component in vue3?

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3

When we use vue2 to create API, we just follow options API like below:

data are in data

methods are in methods

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'demo',
  components: {},
  filter:{},
  mixins:{},
  props: {},
  data(){
    return{
    
    }
  },
  computed:{},
  watch:{},
  methods: {},
}
</script>
```

But the vue3 changed, how should I build a component with vue3 composition API?

Some example say that I should import reactive etc. From vue first and put all codes in `setup(){}`?

Some example show that I can add setup to `<script>`?

Please give me an example.

Comment: 1. You can build component the same way like in Vue 2. 2. There is a lot of articles about it. Not to mention the documentation.

Comment: Or free courses, like on Vue mastery.

Comment: Everything is described in detail here   https://learnvue.co/2020/12/setting-up-your-first-vue3-project-vue-3-0-release/

Answer (score 1):

ok bro , Composition Api works like that:

```
<script>
import { fetchTodoRepo } from '@/api/repos'
import {ref,onMounted} from 'vue'
export default {

setup(props){
const arr = ref([])  // Reactive Reference `arr`
 const getTodoRepo = async () => {
    arr.value = await fetchTodoRepo(props.todo)
  }
  onMounted(getUserRepo) // on `mounted` call `getUserRepo`

return{
arr,
getTodoRepo
}
}


}

</script>
```

Comment: please tell me what is props mean?

Comment: it's mean all info passed by parent components

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to create a component in vue3.

One：`<script>` + `setup(){}`,such as this:

```
<script>
import { reactive, onMounted, computed } from 'vue'

export default {
  props: {
    title: String
  },
  setup (props, { emit }) {
    const state = reactive({
      username: '',
      password: '',
      lowerCaseUsername: computed(() => state.username.toLowerCase())
    })

    onMounted(() => {
      console.log('title: ' + props.title)
    })

    const login = () => {
      emit('login', {
        username: state.username,
        password: state.password
      })
    }

    return { 
      login,
      state
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Two：use `<script setup="props">`

loading....